# Understanding coordinates like (272070.600041, 155389.38792)?

Tags: python, shapefile, coordinate-system

Using the OSGeo4W Shell and working with the code provided by Gene, I am trying to get both latitude and longitude from a .shp file; but am running into errors re the definition of "shape" or "x."  For example, starting at the top of what Gene offered, I am able to:

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr
reader = ogr.Open("a_shape.shp")
layer = reader.GetLayer()
spatialRef = layer.GetSpatialRef()
spatialRef.ExportToProj4()
```

(And my projection is NAD83 California zone 5, also confirmed by SB County).  This much of the fiona code also works:

```
import fiona
c = fiona.open('a_shape.shp')
c.crs
{u'lon_0': -118, u'datum': u'NAD83', u'y_0': 500000.0000000001, u'no_t_2': 35.46666666666667, u'lat_1': 34.03333333333333, u'lat_0': 33.5}
first = c.next()
print first
```

But with the next line:

```
x,y = shape['geometry']['coordinates']
```

I get the error: NameError: name 'shape' is not defined.  Going on, the following works:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
ori = Proj(c.crs)
dest= Proj(init='EPSG:4326')
```

But again, with:

```
transform(ori, dest,x,y)
```

I get an error: "NameError: name 'x' is not defined."  Moving on, this works:

```
from osgeo import osr
spatialRef = layer.GetSpatialRef()
latlong = osr.SpatialReference()
latlong.ImportFromProj4('+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84')  
latlong.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation( spatialRef, latlong  )
```

With the next line, I also get the same error: "NameError: name 'x' is not defined."  "NameError: name 'x' is not defined."

What do these errors mean?

---

NOTE: I am using windows 7, 64 bit. Previously, I was unable to install some packages because of the error "no vcvarsall.bat file."  Upon installing qGIS, the installations worked for fiona, osgeo, and pyproj! I installed them, using the OSGEO4w Shell: "pip install xx.whl", using 64-bit wheels from Christoph Gohlke's site. I could then import them in python.

Comment: Without knowing a general location that the points represent, it's almost impossible to determine the coordinate reference system. Even identifying what state or (smaller) country that they're in might allow someone to narrow down the possibilities. If you know, please edit that info into the question.

Comment: If you're in the US, the coordinates may be State Plane. [NGS](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov) has online converters for state plane and UTM. However, I'm striking out with SPCS, UTM and Teale Albers (a state-wide system). Where did you get this data?

Comment: Oh, should have asked. So there's no shapefile_name.prj file?

Comment: The .prj file will tell you what the projection is.  If you can't paste the link, you can edit the question to include the content of the .prj file

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  As it stands I think your question would benefit from being heavily revised to try and make what you are asking clearer.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Answer (score 3):

#### "Help, I'm new to GIS! What kind of coordinates are these?"

The very first thing you should ask yourself is, "Did this shapefile come with a .prj file?"

If the answer is yes, then congratulations! Your answer is in that file. It's just a text file, open it up and it should contain all you need to know.

If the answer is no, the next question should be "Do I know approximately where this data *should* be?" and if *that* answer is no, then throw that data away and complain to the person who gave you that data, because it's pretty much worthless.

However, if you know about where your data should be, you should still complain to the person who gave you the data, because all coordinates should come with appropriate datum/projection/unit of measure (or Coordinate Reference System) metadata. But at least you can continue.

#### "Is it UTM?"

There's an easy way to tell if your data is UTM. Measure the distance in meters from the equator to your area, and that should roughly be your Y value. There are [a lot of online resources](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=utm%20distance%20calculator) to help with this. (That is, unless you work in the oil and gas industry, which loves to use US survey feet instead of meters, which is technically the BLM projection in NAD27 which sometimes THAT along with international feet get mixed up ohgodpleasehelpme) Ahem.

San Bernardino in UTM (Zone 11) is approximately 3.7 to 3.9 million along Y, which doesn't come close to either of your Y values, so it's probably not UTM. It's worth noting that the above applies to the Northern Hemisphere. Those in the Southern Hemisphere can do the same, but the Equator starts at 10 million Y and you *subtract* the distance to get your approximate Y value.

#### "Great, so it's not UTM. Now what?"

If you are in the United States, there's a good chance your coordinates are in a [State Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Plane_Coordinate_System) projection. State plane projections run along county borders, and San Bernardino falls in California Zone 5 projection. If your data is recent, it's probably in the [NAD83 datum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Datum). Since your data came from the government, you can check this handy chart to see if your state has adopted feet or meters for NAD83:

[image: n83 ft vs meter]

Now if we plot out one of your coordinates - 6676808.9, 1854712.3 - using [NAD83 State Plane California Zone 5 in USFT](http://epsg.io/2229), we get a point pretty much right on San Bernardino city:

[image: Point location]

#### "Great! This is exactly where my data is!"

Nooo, no no nononono. Please no. This is all just a guess! For all you know, I run the San Bernardino GIS department, and all the coordinates are based on my awesome new Mintex Datum of 2016. (I don't, for the record) If you need to be sure, contact the data provider. I can't stress this enough.

#### "Wait, what about the coordinates in the title? They seem way off!"

Those values look too small for a state plane zone coordinate. Perhaps the [False Easting and False Northing values](http://epsg.io/2229) haven't been applied. Adding that to the coordinates puts a point just south of San Bernardino county into Riverside. But again, this is just a guess, see the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple Python dictionary ([GeoJSON format](http://geojson.org/))

```
shape = {"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [272070.60004, 155389.38792]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"DIP_DIR": 130, "DIP": 30, "TYPE": "incl"}, "id": 0}
```

The geometry and coordinates:

```
shape['geometry']
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [272070.60004, 155389.38792]}
shape['geometry']['coordinates']
[272070.60004, 155389.38792]
```

If you want to to convert them to latitude and longitude, you need to know first the crs of the shapefile

```
from osgeo import ogr
reader = ogr.Open("a_shape.shp")
layer = reader.GetLayer()
spatialRef = layer.GetSpatialRef()
spatialRef.ExportToProj4()
'+proj=lcc +lat_1=51.1666672333 +lat_2=49.8333339 +lat_0=90 +lon_0=4.36748666667 +x_0=150000.013 +y_0=5400088.438 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs
```

If we use directly [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) (all dictionaries)

```
import fiona
c = fiona.open('a_shape.shp')
c.crs
{u'lon_0': 4.36748666667, u'ellps': u'intl', u'y_0': 5400088.438, u'no_defs': True, u'proj': u'lcc', u'x_0': 150000.013, u'units': u'm', u'lat_2': 49.8333339, u'lat_1': 51.1666672333, u'lat_0': 90}
first = c.next()
print first
{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [272070.60004, 155389.38792]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"DIP_DIR": 130, "DIP": 30, "TYPE": "incl"},"id": 0}
x,y = shape['geometry']['coordinates']
print x,y
272070.60004 155389.38792
```

Then you can use [pyproj](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj) to convert the coordinates (many examples on GIS SE)

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
ori = Proj(c.crs)
dest= Proj(init='EPSG:4326')
transform(ori, dest,x,y)
(6.09538713219693, 50.69684630470856)
```

and with ogr and osr

```
from osgeo import osr
spatialRef = layer.GetSpatialRef()
latlong = osr.SpatialReference()
latlong.ImportFromProj4('+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84') # or  latlong.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation( spatialRef, latlong  )
transform.TransformPoint(x,y)
(6.095387132182777, 50.69684630470866, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the shapefile you mentioned, but you could try using the `.GetGeoSpatialReference` command within osgeo. Documentation is provided at the [GDAL/OGR cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html#get-projection).